# uClibc vs glibc for real time Linux application programming

Tags: c, linux, glibc, uclibc

I am writing a user space audio application which runs over Linux (Kernel 3.0) , and it need real time behavior. Should I go for glibc or uClibC ? How uClibC and glibc are compared with respect to realtime behavior?

(edit: mine is an embedded system with nand flash. it uses buildroot with external gcc toolchain with glibc. i can also use buildroot internal toolchain with uClibc if required)

Comment: Where is this supposed to run? If on a "normal" Linux userspace, you don't have any choice but glibc. And I very much doubt any use of libc functions could become the performance bottleneck. If glibc works, use that. If you are _sure_ that glibc can't give what you want, measure.

Comment: You could consider also http://www.musl-libc.org/

Answer (score 3):

Realistically, I don't think anyone can say for sure one way or the other. The reason being that your code may well use the C library in a way that is greatly better/worse in one variant than the other.

The only reasonable way is to run the code with glibc, then under the same conditioins with uclibc. Compare the time it takes to do the work. Which is better in your case? - and if this is going into some sort of embedded system, make sure you measure on the processor you want it to run on, not some PC processor that has completely different instruction set, different cache-sized, different memory speed, etc, etc.

You say you use a lot of malloc - maybe if you think that is a limiting factor for your speed, you should consider an approach where you don't use malloc quite so much. In particular, it's not a good idea to call malloc in your "hot-path", unless you absolutely HAVE TO.

Note also that Linux is not a realtime OS. You can only expect semi-realtime behaviour with Linux, and if your application really relies on being able to process it's audio within a certain amount of time, and with certain conditions for how long it can be "not running" etc, you will need to add extensions to the kernel - I'm not quite familiar with WHICH ones are good for which version(s) of kernel, types of workloads, etc.

Comment: what do you mean by semi-realtime behavior ?

Comment: Semi-realtime means something where "failure to meet a deadline isn't catastrophic" - in other words, cases where something dramatically goes wrong, such as "if you miss this deadline, all current calls on the mobile phone basestation goes down" or "if you miss this deadline, the system has to reboot". Those sort of systems are "hard realtime".

Answer (score 0):

I would write your app portably so you can defer the decision to build time. To give you a better answer, we would need to know what realtime features you want to use.

Comment: my application need to process audio data every 20 milliseconds without missing data. my code uses lots of malloc, string comparison and other functions in every 20 millisecond.

Comment: Just set it for realtime priority with the sched functions and call mlockall and you should be safe either way. The only thing that could delay you a whole 20ms is swapping.

Comment: If you need realtime guarantees, you cannot use malloc.

Comment: @Mahmoud: What do you base this on? Supposing the system needs to swap, yes. But given sufficient RAM in the system, it shouldn't be a problem. Not using malloc is just as likely to cause swapping if the system is overcommitted on RAM, so not using malloc won't actually help anything [I'm not suggesting that malloc is a good idea in hot paths, as I explained in my answer, but it's not a "you can't use it" in my mind].

Comment: Any decent malloc impl is O(1) so the only way malloc can be bad for realtime is if it might fail or cause swapping.

Comment: @Mats to the best of my knowledge, on mainstream OSes without realtime kernel patches, the stock `malloc`/`free` are non-deterministic and not guaranteed to be O(1) every time, depending on the internal state, the size of the request, the available free memory, and more. (Again, to the best of my knowledge,) one of the most important characteristics of a real-time OS is the availability of a deterministic `malloc`.

Comment: To be a little more precise, a malloc implementation can be O(1) without being deterministic; a malloc that for all allocation sizes takes 1 µs 99.999% of the time and 1 year 0.001% of the time is still O(1), but not useful for realtime applications.

Comment: @StephenCanon: In that sense, everything is O(1) time and space on a real-world computer because they're all finite state machines. I'm thinking of a [transdichotomous model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transdichotomous_model) where you're imagining real infinite scaling by scaling the word size of the machine logarithmically with your data size, and when I say the malloc algorithms are O(1), I mean even if you scale them arbitrarily in this sense. Of course there's a space cost to this scaling.

Comment: @R..: I'm not imagining any scaling with the data size at all.  I'm attempting to point out that asymptotics of performance (regardless of model) are nearly wholly orthogonal to determinism of performance.

Comment: OK, you're just saying one insanely-slow outlier does not affect big-O, and of course that's true. So I should have used clearer language. The point is that the number of userspace instructions executed by malloc is essentially the same for all runs, and the time varies mostly by things like cache/TLB misses, page faults, and the need to make syscalls for some requests. Assuming swapping does not happen, none of these contingencies are very expensive (certainly not on the order of milliseconds) so OP should be safe.

Comment: @R..: 100% agreed.  And sorry, abuse of O( ) notation is something of a pet peeve =)

Answer (score 0):

Use the C library which is installed on your system. Any given Linux distribution will typically use either glibc (for most distributions, including desktop and server systems) or uClibc (in some embedded distributions). Mixing and matching the two is quite messy, and will make building, debugging, and distributing your application unreasonably complicated.

The performance characteristics of the two libraries are generally quite similar, and are unlikely to have any significant effect on your application.